# Save database schema in file use java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Hi i need to save the database schema in a file. Like Hibernate do in its hbm files (save table names, columns name and types and primary foreign keys) Is there a pattern to do it?

Comment: So you want to read all the database meatdata manually and store it in a file?

Comment: But with or without Hibernate? I say this because you can use HibernateTools that can perform exactly as the hibernate property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto, and write the result in a file (with the creation of tables, cols, keys, constraints, etc.)

Comment: Could be use Hibernate. I need this metadata in a single file because another application will read it.

Comment: do you have some link example about this @richarbernal

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Hibernate class `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport`

You can pass it your Hibernate configuration and then use the method [execute()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html#execute%28boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) wich prints the schema.

This is a code example:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.addResource(mappingFile);  // mapping to your hibernate mapping xml
cfg.setProperties(props);  // hibernate configuration properties, like dialect, connection url, etc.

SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(cfg);
schemaExport.setDelimiter(";");
schemaExport.setOutputFile("database-script.sql");
schemaExport.setFormat(true);
schemaExport.execute(false, false, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

DBlook will do that for you.

http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21381009

http://db.apache.org/derby/javadoc/publishedapi/jdbc4/org/apache/derby/tools/dblook.html